# Django Save Occasionally Fails

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

We have a code like below and when executing `process_something`, sometimes the fields failed to be updated  after `process_something3` successfully executed. Most of the time it works normally but sometimes it just failed to update all mentioned field in the functions (other function that executed between these 3 functions executed normally without problem)

```
from django.db import models


class DjangoObject(models.Model):
    field1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    field2 = models.DateField()
    field3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def process_something(self):
        # Do something here
        self.save(update_fields=['field1'])
        
        self.process_something2()
    
    
    def process_something2(self):
        # Do asynchronous process
        self.process_something3()
    
    
    def process_something3(self):
        # Do another thing here
        self.save(update_fields=['field2', 'field3'])
```

As far as i know it only happens here, so i suspect it caused by race condition by saving on same object. Is it really that or there is other cause and how to fix it ?

Django version is 3.2.9 
Postgresql version is psql (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) 
Asynchronous process using [django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)

Comment: What is the exact behaviour, sometimes when `process_something` is called `field1` is updated but `field2` and `field3` are not? Can you show the code that calls this method

Comment: No, all of them failed to be updated. Other functions that running between these 3 functions are running normally though. The code are private so i can't show it. Sorry

Comment: If the code is private and you can't provide a reproducible example then how do you expect anyone to answer your question?